# Flex: Changing font size of selectedItem in SpinnerList

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I know you can change the fontSize of all the items in a SpinnerList
`example.setStyle("fontSize", 12);`

I tried doing:
`example.selectedItem.setStyle("fontSize", 12);`
but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The reason accessing the selectedItem doesn't work is because that sets the style on an object in the dataProvider; not on the itemRenderer.  You can do this with a custom itemRenderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`example.selectedItem` usually is not a `UIComponent`, but some Value Object. You need to access *itemRenderer* directly or listen style changing from your custom item renderer